# SQLAlchemy: how to reference the parent table as a relationship without an extra query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy how can I reference a table that's already joined with a relationship without an additional query?

```
class CommonMetadata(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)


class Child(CommonMetadata):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("CommonMetadata.id"), primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String)
    common_metadata = relationship("CommonMetadata")
```

For example when I do this:

```
child = session.query(Child).get(1)
child.common_metadata
```

An additional join is done on accessing `child.common_metadata` despite the fact that `Child` already has that data (because it is a join of Child and CommonMetadata).

---

SQLAlchemy won't let me do this either:

```
child = session.query(Child).join(CommonMetadata).first()
```

As SQLAlchemy notices the redundant join:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateAlias) table name "common" specified more than once
```

However I can do this:

```
child, _ = session.query(Child, CommonMetadata).first()
```

But it's not the nicest API.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Child` and `CommonMetaData`? Is it many to one or one to one or many to many?

Comment: Sorry ignore this. It's actually...

Comment: CommonMetadata could have many children.   But that's not the intention of my design since it's fairly useless on its own.  I don't really plan on querying CommonMetadata on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work automatically I need to define a polymorphic identity on the parent and child.

```
class CommonMetadata(Base):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'common_metadata',
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)


class Child(CommonMetadata):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'child',
    }

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("CommonMetadata.id"), primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String)
    common_metadata = relationship("CommonMetadata")
```

I don't fully understand why, but I imagine it's just additional information for the mapper.

Comment: Sometimes it seems that when you feel you reach the end of what's possible with SQLAlchemy you just scratch your head for a bit and it magically starts working for you again.